# VM questions from a beginner

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, performance

Sorry if these questions have answers that should be obvious, but I am quite new to VM's and not well-versed at it. So I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my virtual machine and everything works, but I have noticed that it is not exactly smooth in the way booting of a USB drive would show. I know that a virtual machine has it's limits, but I want to make my experience smoother if possible. Any suggestions to increase the performance of my Ubuntu virtual machine would be very appreciated.

I have read that something called Intel VTx can use all of my CPU power, which is what I observe to be limiting the performance for smooth 1080p video playback from YouTube. I am using 4 cores and 4GB of R.A.M. along with 128MB of VRAM for my virtual machine.

Comment: Enable VTx in your BIOS. Check resource consumption (`top` and `free`) in both guest and host to find CPU and RAM bottlenecks. Check /var/log/syslog for errors and warnings before and during the time of a slowdown.

Comment: @user535733 Uhm, sorry, but I don't really understand what you mean by top, free, /var/log/syslog. I got the VTx thing, but not sure about the rest, could you explain a little more? Thank you.

Comment: Look up the commands and paths that you don't understand. That's your homework: How to open a terminal and enter simple commands and paths. Example: Try the command `man top` for an explanation of the `top` command.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are running Ubuntu 20.04 in your VM and have given it 4 cores and 4GB of RAM, but you haven't mentioned what the host OS is, how many CPU cores the host has or what hypervisor you are using. Based on that, I can only answer this in the most generic of terms.

1) Don't give all of your CPU cores to the VM. If you have 4 CPU cores, give only 3 to the VM. This will reduce the total throughput but will reduce the performance jitter because the VM kernel has no way of telling that the host OS has un-scheduled it in order for the host to run something on the physical CPU core.

2) Make sure you configure the VM to expose the underlying CPU topology. If you have 4 cores / 8 threads on the host and you are passing 3 cores / 6 threads to the VM, configure the VM appropriately to expose this information to the guest VM. This will allow the guest's kernel to schedule processes more sanely.

3) Pin logical CPU threads to physical CPU threads. The way to do this will be specific to the hypervisor you are using.

4) If you are on a NUMA system and your VM is smaller than a NUMA node, make sure it's CPU cores and memory are all allocted on a single NUMA node. This will ensure memory latency is consistent throughput it's range and that you are not inducing unnecessary CPU cache misses. This is mostly relevant if you have a system with more than one CPU socket, or multiple dies on one CPU socket (e.g. Core 2 quad or AMD Zen).

5) Use appripriate paravirtualized drivers for storage and graphics.

Any other advice over and above this will need to be specific to the hypervisor you are using.